# creating logical expression in mysql to extract data from a table

Tags: mysql, logic

I have a data set that looks like this:

[image]

my mission is to Write a logical condition in MySQL based on the check-in and check-out dates to retrieve all stays that
include (the night of) March 23rd. I tried this :

```
check_in<="23/03/2019" and check_out>"23/03/2019"
```

but I found out that stayed with `check-in = ‘2019-03-21’` and `check-out =
‘2019-03-25’` wasn't retrieved even though it includes the 23r. I wonder what is the problem and how could I fix it? thank you :)

Comment: What is the full query you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery that groups by stay_id and checks your requirement in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select * 
from tablename
where stay_id in (
  select stay_id from tablename
  group by stay_id
  having '2019-03-23' between 
    max(case when event_type = 'check-in' then date end) and max(case when event_type = 'check-out' then date end)
)
```

or since a check-out date is (I assume) later than or equal to a check-in date:

```
select * 
from tablename
where stay_id in (
  select stay_id from tablename
  group by stay_id
  having '2019-03-23' between min(date) and max(date)
)
```

Or if you want 1 row for each `stay_id`:

```
select stay_id, min(date) check_in_date, max(date) check_out_date
from tablename
group by stay_id
having '2019-03-23' between min(date) and max(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join it with itself to be able to search on both terms.  Assuming your table is called `stays`:

`SELECT a.stay_id,a.date check_in,b.date check_out FROM stays a JOIN stays b ON a.stay_id=b.stay_id AND a.event_type='check-in' AND b.event_type='check-out' WHERE a.date<="2019-03-23" AND b.date>"2019-03-23";`

Answer (score 0):

Assume everyone checked out:

```
select stay_id
from tbl
where event_type = 'check-in' and date <=  '2019-03-23'
and stay_id in
(select stay_id
from tbl
where event_type = 'check-out' and date > '2019-03-23')
```

I can edit later to create a logic to include people not checked out yet